# There are how many?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, nonogram

<sup>*This is an entry in the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet).*</sup>

---

Here is a fun nonogram I made to celebrate! Celebrate what you ask? That is for you to find out. Solve the nonogram to find out how many, and include what it is that is being referred to.

[image]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits to @Dorrulf for solving the nonogram (borrowing it here):

> [image]

I believe that you are celebrating ...

> Being the 15 thousandth question posted (or if you're not exactly that, then you're simply celebrating puzzling.stackexchange's milestone)

Comment: Hah, finally found it... Was simpler than I thought. Well done.

Comment: @Dorrulf thanks for solving the time-consuming part lol

Comment: Was the part I was most interested in anyways. It's what I get for using puzzling.stackexchange.com instead of puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions xD

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> [image]

Will work on what this means

Out of all the potential pieces I'm seeing (here are some):

> Numbers: 1, 5, 0
>  Words: I, No, Thou

The best I can come up with is:

> I C 5 Thousand.

But I don't know what that means yet.